# Difference between Custom User and User Profile

Tags: django, django-models

What's the difference between `CustomUser` that inherits `AbstractUser` and adds some custom fields, and `UserProfile` that also adds custom fields?
What's more up-to-date to use?

Answer (score 0):

A custom user *replaces* the `User` model. A user profile *adds to* the user model.

Neither one is more up-to-date, they simply have different use-cases, and which one you use (or both) is a design decision. As long as any and all authentication- and permission-related information is stored on your `CustomUser`, Django is happy, but depending on your exact use-case, one may work better than the other. There's no general answer to that.

Just keep in mind that each user, including admins and superusers is-a `CustomUser`, but each user *may* have-a `UserProfile`.

Comment: @Andrew also note that the **non-authentication** and **non-permission** related information should be stored inside your `UserProfile`. (linked via `OneToOneField`).

Comment: @Andrew, In general, if you are new to Django, you are mostlikely only have to worry about `UserProfile`.

Comment: @Andrew, Refer to the [latest docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for extending User.

Comment: @Yeo I don't necessarily agree with your first comment. If you're not sure, then yes, that's the safest approach. As with any design, you should carefully consider pros and cons, but there are definitely valid reasons to store other information on the user model.

Comment: Hmm.... in general, that's the convention I used, but yes, you're right, there could be cases where it doesn't hold, but I can't think of it at the moment.